# KVO (IOS 5) on simple types (non NSObject)

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I'm having problems to make the **IOS (objective-c) KVO** work for a key of type int.

My class declares a property **sampleValue** of type int. As int doesn't automatically implement the KVO functionality I've overrided the method **automaticallyNotifiesObserversforKey** as this:

```
+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:(NSString *)theKey {

    BOOL automatic = NO;
    if ([theKey isEqualToString:@"sampleValue"]) {
        automatic = NO;
    } else {
        automatic=[super automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:theKey];
    }
    return automatic;
}
```

The method is called just as I would expect is to be. I also have implemented a setter method for the sampleValue property like this:

```
- (void) setSampleValue:(int)newSampleValue
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"sampleValue"];
    sampleValue = newSampleValue;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"sampleValue"];
}
```

Setting up the observer in the observer class is done like this (dc is the instance of the observed object):

```
[dc addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sampleValue" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

However, when the sampleValue is updated, no notification is sent to my observer object. Updating another property of type NSDate works absolutely fine.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or what I should do to make this work.

Best regards
Tomo

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but you can observe properties of type `int` just as easily as other types without doing anything special.

Try removing your `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` override and your `-setSampleValue:` setter, and just synthesize the accessors for `sampleValue`:

```
@synthesize sampleValue;
```

`int` is the type of the value that corresponds to key `@"sampleValue"`, but it's not the thing being observed. The object being observed is `dc`, and it'll take care of sending the proper notification when the `sampleValue` property is changed.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. I think I was guessing that int didn't support KVO as I wasn't able to make it function. I deleted the methods you mentioned which didn't help. Next I added self. in front of the property to be observed so it now has self.sampleValue = ... That made it work. I now get a message in my observer object when sampleValue is updated.

Comment: Figured it out myself. Sorry to disturb. Thanks anyway for your contribute.

Comment: Right -- you need to set the `sampleValue` property, not the corresponding instance variable. It's the property setter that'll cause the message to be sent. That means you need to write `self.sampleValue = ...` or `[self setSampleValue:...]`.

Comment: @user1152964: you should still mark Calebs answer as accepted so that question is marked as closed. And the answer is correct :)