# Observer for an integer property

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I got an an integer property, which value might change during run-time. Therefore, I would like to register this property to an observer in order to receive a notification and call method, if this value has changed. I red already the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) but as far as I understand this is just working for `NSObjects` and not for integers. In my `.h` I created `@property int activePlayer;`.

This is what I am doing in my `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.activePlayer addObserver:playerChangedObserver
          forKeyPath:@"activePlayer"
             options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                      NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
             context:NULL];
```

Looking forward for some help. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Maybe you need some additional information. The `.h` and `.m` are implementing an `UIViewController`, in which I am using a flick gesture. If the gesture is weak, the `int` is 1, if it is a bit stronger it will change to `2`. In my project it makes sense to use this variable, so I can't remove it.

I changed the observer registration into:

```
[self addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"activePlayer"
                 options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                          NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                 context:NULL];
```

The first `self` is the observed object, from which the property comes from. The key-path is the property and the second `self` I took, because it also should receive the message, if the key changes. Do I misunderstand something there?

Comment: Did you search?  Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888623/kvo-ios-5-on-simple-types-non-nsobject

Comment: Yes, but since I am not working with different objects, this solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you actually tried this code? The [introductory example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) for key-value observing is for an integer property. It states further on that

> If the property is a scalar or a C structure, the value is wrapped in an NSValue object (as with key-value coding).

So, you'll need to unpack it before you can do anything with it, but it should work as is.

Comment: There was just an issue in the method, where I updated `activePlayer` so the part in my question under **UPDATE** works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should implement in your .m

```
observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:
```

and you should use

```
self.activePlayer = 1;
```

to set your 'activePlayer' property

Comment: How this should solve my problem? I implemented the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method, but obviously there must be something wrong.